# CgridView pagination link

Tags: yii, pagination, cgridview

In my project, i am using cgridview to display some information and using the pagination built with the cgrid view. but now i am facing a usability problem with pagination. that's, consider i have 3 pages and the pagination looks like **<< < 1 2 3 > >>**.
when i clicked the 3rd page the pagination should look like **<< < 1 2 3** and in case of 1st page the pagination should look like **1 2 3 > >>**. how can i do this. please provide me a solution.

my widget looks like.

```
$widget = $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                    'id' => 'request-grid',
                    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
                    'cssFile' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/media/css/gridview.css',
                    'summaryText' => '',
                    'enablePagination' => true,
                    'template' => '{items}',
                    'pager' => array(
                        'class' => 'LinkPager',
                        'cssFile' => false,
                        'header' => false,
                        'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
                        'prevPageLabel' => 'Previous',
                        'nextPageLabel' => 'Next',
                        'lastPageLabel' => 'Last',
                    ),
                    'columns' => array(......));
```

also i am extending the CLinkPager class in the the component LinkPager.

```
class LinkPager extends CLinkPager
{
    public $maxButtonCount=3;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your css file you need to write

```
.yiiPager .hidden, .yiiPager .first, .yiiPager .last {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you buddy. you are a super hero in Yii specialy CGridView... thanks alot.